# SQL Join resulting in multiple duplicate entries

Tags: sql, left-join, zoho

I'm having troubles figuring out how to get rid of the dupes from the first table. please see highlighted rows here for reference [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5287k.jpg)

This is the formaula I'm inputting

```
SELECT
     "Classes.Class Name" AS Customer,
     "Customers.Customer Name" as docket,
     "Items.Item Name" as EST_Item,
     Quantity as EST_Qty,
     "Unit Price" as EST_UnitPrice,
     "Query_Bill Line items"."Items.Item Name" as BILL_Item,
     "Query_Bill Line items"."Quantity" as Bill_Qty,
     "Query_Bill Line items"."Unit Price" as Bill_UnitPrice
FROM  "Query_Estimate Line Items" LEFT JOIN "Query_Bill Line Items" ON "Query_Estimate Line Items"."cUSTOMERS.cUSTOMER NAME"  = "Query_Bill Line Items"."CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER NAME"
 AND    "Query_Estimate Line Items"."iTEMS.ITEM NAME"  = "Query_Bill Line Items"."ITEMS.ITEM NAME"
```

Sorry for the super long column names! What am I missing to get rid of the dupes from Table1 ""Query_Estimate Line Items"?

Thanks

Comment: The records are not duplicates as the `Bill_Qty` differs.  How do you want to reduce the pairs to a single record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reduce your row count you need to group by something (such as Customer, Docket, EST_Item), and aggregate your non-grouped columns (such as Bill_Qty or Unit_Price). Do you know how to use group by?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I am having problems with the Group by. I have tried and tried and unable to get the result to Group by ["Items.Item Name" as EST_Item]. What I'm hoping to achieve is one Est_Item per Docket with a sum of EST_Qty, Avg of EST_UnitPrice, Sum of Bill_Qty, and Avg of Bill_UnitPrice.